# How do I navigate to the end of the braces when in insert mode in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

[image]

While trying to access the array elements, I frequently run into a small inconvenience of navigating to the end of the `]`. The bracket is autogenerated by the code completion tool when I enter the `[`.

Here is an example to explain the situation.

1. I will write `sum[` in the editor.
2. It will auto-add the `]` making it `sum[]`.
3. I will write the variable inside the array as `sum[cursor]`.
4. Now I will have to go to the end of the `]` to write another code.
5. For navigating, I will press `ESC` and `shift a`.

Is there a shortcut to go after the end of the word while in insert mode?

Answer (score 0):

This mapping may help:

```
inoremap <c-l> <esc>%%a
```

The example above uses `ctrl-l` as the key.
When you're typing inside a pair (`(, [, { .. }, ], )` ), this mapping should work. `<ctrl-l>` in insert mode will bring you after the corresponding pair-end.

Comparing to your `A` approach, this mapping work also when you're modifying existing content inside a pair. `ctrl-l` will always bring you after the pair-end. Your 'A' will move the cursor to the end of the line.

(note, not work for `"..." or '...'`) as they are not pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<Right>` and take a moment to ponder whether that automatic closing is *really* worth it or not.

Comment: The autocomplete is not needed for the array but it is useful for the function's curly braces.
I often alternate between using a web ide on platform like leetcode and local vscode. It's not always possible to configure the autocomplete option.